# Caffe Multilabel not working as expected

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I've played with Caffe for a long time but never done multilabel classification and it seems I'm getting stuck:

### What I'm using

- First of all, I'm creating the lmdb (`train_lmdb`, `val_lmdb`), labels (`labels_train_lmdb`, `labels_val_lmdb`) and mean (`mean_lmdb.binaryproto`) with [Caffe-LMDBCreation-MultiLabel](https://github.com/sukritshankar/Caffe-LMDBCreation-MultiLabel/).
- The model has around 13000 images for 7 classes.
- 2000 of those images have two classes (for example, the vector is [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
- The rest of the images have only one class (for example, the vector would be [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

### What I'm expecting

I'm expecting, at least, to grab an image from the train dataset, for example:

> img1.jpg 0 0 0 1 0 0 0

classify it, and have a value similar to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

### What I'm having instead

for the image above (img1.jpg), I'm having these type of results:

`[0.48112139105796814, 0.5486980676651001, 0.5396456122398376, 0.44233766198158264, 0.5605107545852661, 0.3539462387561798, 0.5215630531311035]`

which doesn't make sense. I've tried with several snapshots (one each 10000 iterations) and results are similar, **all of them really close to 0.50**

### My `prototxt`

**train_val.prototxt**

```
name: "multi-class-alexnet"
# --------------------------------- TRAIN -------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 180
    mean_file: "./mean_lmdb.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "./train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

# ---------------------------- TRAIN LABELS -----------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
    mean_value: 0
  }
  data_param {
    source: "./labels_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

# ---------------------------------- VAL --------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 180
    mean_file: "./mean_lmdb.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "./val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

# ----------------------------- VAL LABELS ------------------------------
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
    mean_value: 0
  }
  data_param {
    source: "./labels_val_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32
    backend: LMDB
  }
}

layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6_"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6_"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc6_"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc6_"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "latent"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "latent"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 48
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "latent"
  top: "latent_sigmoid"
  name: "latent_sigmoid"
  type: "Sigmoid"
}
layer {
  name: "fc9"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "latent_sigmoid"
  top: "fc9"
  param {
    lr_mult: 10
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 20
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 7
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.2
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "MultiLabelAccuracy"
  bottom: "fc9"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------- Multi-label Loss Function  -------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SigmoidCrossEntropyLoss"
  bottom: "fc9"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

**deploy.prototxt**:

```
name: "multi-class-alexnet"
input: "data"
input_shape {
  dim: 10
  dim: 3
  dim: 180
  dim: 180
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 11
    stride: 4
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm1"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "norm2"
  type: "LRN"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "norm2"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0001
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "norm2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 384
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    group: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc6_"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6_"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc6_"
}
layer {
  name: "drop6"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc6_"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc7"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc6_"
  top: "fc7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4096
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layer {
  name: "drop7"
  type: "Dropout"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "latent_"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "latent_"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 7
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "latent_"
  top: "latent_sigmoid"
  name: "latent_sigmoid"
  type: "Sigmoid"
}
```

### Loss function

- Somehow my model is showing two losses, which I don't understand, losses on output #0 and #5. These are the `grep` of the last lines (over 110000 iterations):

**output #0**:

> I0427 10:20:04.475754  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0867133 (* 1 = 0.0867133 loss)
>
> I0427 10:20:38.257825  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0477974 (* 1 = 0.0477974 loss)
>
> I0427 10:21:11.794013  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0390092 (* 1 = 0.0390092 loss)
>
> I0427 10:21:45.620671  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.039954 (* 1 = 0.039954 loss)
>
> I0427 10:22:19.271747  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0477802 (* 1 = 0.0477802 loss)
>
> I0427 10:22:53.160802  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0406158 (* 1 = 0.0406158 loss)
>
> I0427 10:23:26.843694  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0355715 (* 1 = 0.0355715 loss)
>
> I0427 10:24:31.727321  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0396538 (* 1 = 0.0396538 loss)
>
> I0427 10:25:05.019598  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.037121 (* 1 = 0.037121 loss)
>
> I0427 10:25:38.730303  1817 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 0.0362058 (* 1 = 0.0362058 loss)

**output #5**:

> I0427 09:26:52.251719  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 6.98116 (* 1 = 6.98116 loss)
>
> I0427 09:33:01.639736  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 6.99285 (* 1 = 6.99285 loss)
>
> I0427 09:39:09.991879  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 7.02165 (* 1 = 7.02165 loss)
>
> I0427 09:45:18.013739  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 7.01533 (* 1 = 7.01533 loss)
>
> I0427 09:51:27.065721  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 7.02347 (* 1 = 7.02347 loss)
>
> I0427 09:58:13.271441  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 6.98176 (* 1 = 6.98176 loss)
>
> I0427 10:05:31.896226  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 6.99103 (* 1 = 6.99103 loss)
>
> I0427 10:12:12.693677  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 7.02868 (* 1 = 7.02868 loss)
>
> I0427 10:18:23.250385  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 7.03427 (* 1 = 7.03427 loss)
>
> I0427 10:24:31.239820  1817 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #5: loss = 6.97721 (* 1 = 6.97721 loss)

Comment: why do you Scale the input labels?

Comment: @Shai, according to the Caffe-LMDBCreation-MultiLabel (click in the link to go to the GitHub repository), my original labels are in format [0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0], or [255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0]. I didn't use that notation as it doesn't make sense

Comment: Just saying, @Shai, I tried to remove the `scale` and replacing the `255` to `1`, the loss shown in the 5 outputs is different, it converges, but still the same senseless results.